# EPPLus: load csv with respect to the existing styles in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have to load an existed xlsx with predefiend cell styles, and paste data from csv to it.

I know I can

> package.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells[1,1].Value ="somevalue"

without overwrite the original styles.

but to deal with a csv with so many data, I shouldn't write the data 1 by 1, right?

So I tried:

> package.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells[1,1].LoadFromText("csvTableStr"
> , new ExcelTextFormat()
> , TableStyles.None
> , false);

and find that the styles(background color, data type, cell border and so on) are all reset to plain.

I am wondering if there is an option to load the data with respect to the existed styles, something like "TableStyles.Current". Or maybe a way to workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd argument of `LoadFromText()` is a Nullable. So, you may pass null to this argument if you don't want to apply a predefined style to your table. Try this:

```
package.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells[1,1].LoadFromText("csvTableStr" , new ExcelTextFormat() , null , false);
```